# Why does "The Swift Programming Language" say it is possible to join a character and a string to a new string while my playground doesn't allow it?

Tags: swift

So I'm currently reading Apple's documentation/guide to their new programming language Swift.
Under the headline „Concatenating Strings and Characters“ it said that strings and characters can be joined to form a new string and an example is provided.

```
let string1 = " there"
let character1: Character = "!"
let characterPlusString = character1 + string1
```

But when I execute this, all examples that join a string and a character throw the error:
 `<EXPR>:15:38: error: cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '(Character, String)` 
I'm using the playground in XCode Version 6.0.1 (6A317) 
I've already done some research but up to this point found nothing. Has the language been updated? (the book wasn't) Thanks for all answers, I'm sorry if this question has already been asked and I didn't find it.

Comment: Post the code, so we can see if you have made a mistake :)

Comment: The language has changed, but the book has been updated as well. The [current documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_418) states: *"NOTE: You can’t append a String or Character to an existing Character variable, because a Character value must contain a single character only."* – I would recommend that you download an up-to-date version of the book.

Comment: Hey Martin, I think he wants to add a character into a String which is possible using the .append method. Adding a string or a character to a Character was not allowed in any iteration of the language since a Character can only contain a single character!

Comment: @RajeevBhatia: You are right, the "NOTE" does not apply here. But in early versions of Swift you could mix characters and strings freely. If I remember correctly, `someChar + someString` (yielding a *string*) was valid then.  Therefore updating the documentation should be helpful to the OP in any case.

Comment: Good point Martin and I think that concatenation using "+" for strings and characters was allowed before and returned a String so if you took it in a String variable(or just a var since that would be String), it won't be a problem but if you took it in a char such as somechar = somechar + somestring, that would yield the same problems. If only the iBooks were properly updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_428

You can add strings and characters using the append function

```
var helloString = "hello"
let exclamationMark: Character = "!"
helloString.append(exclamationMark)
helloString//prints "hello!"
```

if you must use the "+" operator, you will have to typecast your character

```
helloString = helloString + String(exclamationMark)
helloString//prints "hello!"
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: OK, thanks; so the language has apparently been updated (iBooks simply does not tell me :) )

Comment: @Mastombord: Yes, for some reason updating the Swift books automatically does not always work (for me). What I do is to delete and re-download the books after a new Xcode/Swift version has been released

Comment: Thanks for accepting as answer :). And I generally prefer referring to the web version of the documentation since that will always be the most updated version. Ofcourse you have to fall back to the pdf/iBooks version if you do not have net connectivity at that moment